# How to show JSON response in a JSP page after making a REST URL Call

Tags: java, json, jsp, spring-mvc

I have made a form using JSP. I have to make a REST URL using that form and then after making that url from the form, I need to hit that url using RestTemplate and get the response back. I am able to get the response back from that url.

**Problem Statement:-**

When I copy paste that url into the browser, I ususally gets a JSON response. So is there any way I can get the same JSON response from that URL apart from the String I am getting? Currently I am storing that as a String and then showing a String as a response into other output form which looks very boring. Is there any better way to show the JSON output using the JSP page?

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/showResponse", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String showResponse(@ModelAttribute("berequest") @Valid RequestForm berequest, BindingResult errors,
        ModelMap model) {

        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder()
            .append("http://" + berequest.getMachineName() + ":" + berequest.getPortNumber()+ "/service/EEService/v1/get/")
            .append("USERID=" + berequest.getUserId())
            .append(",")
            .append("TIMEOUT=" + berequest.getWaitTimeout())
            .append("/")
            .append(berequest.getAttributeNames().toLowerCase());

        System.out.println("URL: " + url);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        // I believe I need to change here
        String result = restTemplate.getForObject(url.toString(), String.class);
        System.out.println(result);

        model.addAttribute("response", result);

        return "resultform"; // showing the response into other jsp page
    }
```

Below is the **resultform jsp page**

```
<fieldset>
            <legend>Response:</legend>
                <strong>${response}</strong><br />

        </fieldset>
```

So currently it looks very boring. Any better way to show the JSON response?

**UPDATE:-**

Suppose I am getting this JSON response back from the URL that I am making with the form

```
{
    "attributes": [
        {
            "nm": "ACCOUNT",
            "lv": [
                {
                    "v": {
                        "Id": null,
                        "State": null
                    },
                    "vt": "java.util.Map",
                    "cn": 1
                }
            ],
            "vt": "java.util.Map",
            "status": "SUCCESS",
            "lmd": 13585
        },
        {
            "nm": "PROFILE
            "lv": [
                {
                    "v": {
                        "Party": null,
                        "Ads": null
                    },
                    "vt": "java.util.Map",
                    "cn": 2
                }
            ],
            "vt": "java.util.Map",
            "status": "SUCCESS",
            "lmd": 41962
        }
    ]
}
```

So currently it is getting shown as a String in a Single Line in my JSP page something like this which I don't want.

```
{attributes=[{nm=ACCOUNT, lv=[{v={Id=null, State=null}, vt=java.util.Map, cn=1}], vt=java.util.Map, status=SUCCESS, lmd=1358535241962}]}
```

I need to show it exactly as it is shown above as a response in my JSP page. So that people can understand each field properly.

**Updated**

POJO for the JSON I made-

```
public class UrlInfo implements Serializable {

    private List<Attributes> attribute;

}

class Attributes {

    private String nm;
    private List<ValueList> lv;
    private String vt;
    private String status;
    private String lmd;

}


class ValueList {
    private String vt;
    private String cn;
    private List<String> v;
}
```

Can anyone take a look and let me know whether it is right basis on my JSON string?

Comment: what about code tag:  `<code>${response}</code>`

Comment: Thanks elbek for the suggestion? So you are saying I should modify only the JSP file with the code tag right? by replacing strong tag?

Comment: u can not make your java object like output with just tag. U need to use some json libraries to print like that. <code> can not do what u are expecting.

Comment: Thanks elbek. Can you provide me any example related to my code what and where I need to do the changes?

Comment: What's `-` in your json string?

Comment: `-` here means expand collapse sign. When I copy pasted it, it also got copied.

Comment: Sorry, your json string is not validated. Please validate your json here [http://jsonlint.com/](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Yup, it was wrong somehow. Sorry about that. I updated my question with correct JSON. Let me know if basis on that my POJO looks good? Or I need to modify something?

Comment: @TechGeeky I put an another answer on you json code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper`:

```
public static Map<?, ?> toMap(String json) {
    try {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return objectMapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        log.error("", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

And you can use `response` as a `Map` in you jsp.

```
model.addAttribute("response", toMap(result));
```

---

Also you can convert string to `JavaBean` :

```
public static <T> T toObject(String json, Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return objectMapper.readValue(json, clazz);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        log.error("", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

in you code:

```
User user = toObject(response,User.class);
model.add('user',user);
```

---

UPDATE:

if you json like this:

```
{
"id": "1",
"name": "oliver",
"address": [
    {
        "zip": 124,
        "add": "China"
    },
    {
        "zip": 345,
        "add": "USA"
    }
]
}
```

You can define `JavaBean`:

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private Integer id:
    private String name;
    private List<Address> address;
}
```

Comment: Thanks lichengwu for the suggestion. After trying this I didn't got the way I needed means in the way an actual JSON response should look like. I got something like this in a single line-  `{attributes=[{nm=ACCOUNT, lv=[{v={Id=null, userate=null}, vt=java.util.Map, cn=1}], vt=java.util.Map, status=SUCCESS, lmd=13585352}]}`. I want output should be shown in my JSP page something like this in this link [http://json.org/example.html](http://json.org/example.html). As when I hit the url that I am making from the form it gives me JSON response like in the above link I showed you.

Comment: How can I use response as a Map in my JSP? Maybe that's the part I am missing?

Comment: Sorry, i did not get you point. What do you want? Using the json as an Object or Map in you jsp or just display use json string in page?

Comment: Updated the question with more details what I needed. I guess I will be needing as a Object.

Comment: Updated again with output I am getting

Comment: Hi lichengwu, I updated my question with the POJO I got from the JSON. Can you take a look and let me know if it looks good to you?

Answer (score 0):

As your json, the `JavaBean` may like this:

ValueList.class:

```
class ValueList implements Serializable{

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7932712012947938597L;
  private String vt;
  private String cn;
  private Map<String,Object> v;

}
```

Attributes.class:

```
class Attributes implements Serializable{

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -4743479664824391040L;
  private String nm;
  private List<ValueList> lv;
  private String vt;
  private String status;
  private String lmd;

}
```

UrlInfo.class:

```
class UrlInfo implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -2098738691615474311L;

  private List<Attributes> attributes;

}
```

PS:The getter/setter methods are omitted above.